# Is it possible to link the Shazam Encore app to the online My Shazam account?

Tags: shazam

It seems like I'm missing something.  My phone has about 20 songs on it and when I logged into My Shazam today I expected them to show up.  Instead I find the following.

> [image]

The Shazam 'My Account' settings ask for the phone number of the device; which is entered.  No where on the site can I find verifications that tags *shouldn't* be synced.

Is it just me or is tagged song syncing not available?